# Django formset return empty instances

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset, inline-formset

I have a class that inheirts from BaseInlineFormSet, where I override the save() method:

```
class CustomBaseModelFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def save(self, something=None, commit=True, *args, **kwargs):
        instances = super(CustomBaseModelFormSet, self).save(commit=False)
```

but when I call formset.save() to create new objects with a bound and valid formset, the variable instances is an empty list!

Why the the save() of the parent class is not saving? there's no trace of any error.

I'm using Python 3 and Django 1.10.5.

Comment: You set commit to False, but is it True somewhere further along the road?

Comment: Yes. Anyway, setting commit to False, the instances should be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that in the BaseModelFormSet class, there's a save_new_objects() method that was skipping my forms to be saved due to the following check:

```
if not form.has_changed():
    continue
```

So, in my ModelForm I overwrote this method:

```
def has_changed(self):
    return True
```

This way it always return True and my forms are saved.